# EMR/boto - How to get cluster id and step id using boto?

Tags: boto, emr, amazon-emr

There are some `describe_*` functions in `boto.emr` need *step_id*. But the document does not describe very clearly how to obtain the step_id after submitting steps.

How can I get these step_ids after `run_jobflow` or `add_steps`?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information and/or code to show what you are trying to do?  The question is a bit vague.

Comment: Check out boto's doc: http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/emr.html , we can there's `describe_step(cluster_id, step_id)` function, but there's no any return value or something mentioned about how get the step_id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The job-id (cluster id) can be found on the `boto.emr.emrobject.JobFlow` via the `jobflowid` method:

```
(Pdb) job().jobflowid returns: u'j-BZC0X65JLLEA'
```

for the step id for a given step, you can use the list_steps method on the connection, for example:

```
(Pdb) conn().list_steps('j-BZC0X65JLLEA').steps[-1].id returns: u's-1A1ASN2W23Y1L'
```

Calling steps will give you a list of `boto.emr.emrobject.StepSummary` objects, you can iterate over those and pluck out what you need.